# Centrar horizontal y verticalmente un botón HTML con CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy queriendo centrar un texto, tanto horizontal como verticalmente. Usé Flexbox, pero no da resultado, no sé si hay un error. Al botón lo programo con HTML y lo estilizo con CSS.

```css
.Primera_Caja_con_texto {
    
     padding-top: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 460px;
     padding-right: 5px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     background-color: white;
     border-color: #737373;
     border-style: solid;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     
    
}
```

```html
<div class="Primera_Caja_con_texto">
                <strong> N1 en el mercado automotriz, especializándonos en Cerrajería y Accesorios del automotor.
                </strong>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usas padding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox precisamente facilita el tema de los centrados verticales. Mira esta solución, el texto queda centrado vertical y horizontalmente en el bloque. Le he puesto un alto de 400px para que sea evidente el doble centrado.

```css
.Primera_Caja_con_texto {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height:400px;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: #737373;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="Primera_Caja_con_texto">
     <strong> N1 en el mercado automotriz, especializándonos en Cerrajería y Accesorios del automotor<strong>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sí, lo que ha faltado es ponerle altura al elemento.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

He de comentarte que el error inicial es que para lograr el objetivo planteado mezcles el uso de padding junto con las bondades de [*flexbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

En este caso debes tener presente que al darle valores a [*padding-x: algo;*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding) estas separando al contenido de su contenedor, en este caso el texto.

**Opciones**

1. Dado lo anterior, entonces claramente debes guiarte con la respuesta del otro usuario.
2. Dar una misma medida de padding para (*top, left, right, bottom*), lo cual te ayudará a separar de manera uniforme al contenido (mismo que recomendaría pertenezca a una etiqueta que ayude a manipularlo de manera posterior como una [etiqueta `p`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)) y alinear el texto al centro

```html
    <style>
      .Primera_Caja_con_texto {
         border-color: #737373;
         border-style: solid;
         font-weight: bold;
         padding: 50px;
         text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="Primera_Caja_con_texto">
      <p>
          N1 en el mercado automotriz.
      </p>
    </div>
```